# Diagnosing the cause of slow Oracle application

Tags: database, performance, oracle, networking, oracle11g

We have a windows application that saves data to an Oracle database - this is nothing particularly complicated, it is just adding a row with a few numbers to a table. This application has been installed at one of my clients for many years and has worked absolutely fine. However, now they have relocated their Oracle servers to another country and are complaining that now my application is running very slowly.

I am fairly sure that this can only be something related to network speeds at their end, and not anything to do with our application.

Are there any tools out there that will help diagnose the exact cause of the slowness? Also, are there anything that could be modified in my program to make it work faster in situations where the Oracle database is remote?

Thanks!

### UPDATE

A user has to fill in a few numbers in textboxes and then clicks a button, which sends these results to the database. It also updates a 'summary' table for the users session, basically just saving how many times the user has clicked the button. So that's one insert and one update. The only other thing is an audit trail which saves about 20 one-column rows of data to another table. Is this really enough to make an application slow down to the point where it's unusable?

We're not doing anything like reconnecting every time we send an SQL query - the connection is made once at the start of the program and closed when it exits.

Comment: That's not much to go on. Presumably it's querying data, not just saving it, but is it doing lots of individual inserts? Are you using connection pooling or opening a new connection for each query/insert? When querying are you using a sensible fetch size? Are you pulling data back to validate new entries locally or doing that within the DB? Etc. The amount of network traffic you're generating is dependent on how you've designed the interaction between the app and the DB, and switching a large amount of traffic from LAN to WAN can make a big difference, even without network problems.

Comment: "it is just adding a row with a few numbers to a table" Is it doing this a million times in a loop?  You need to at least add a layer of debugging that will profile the slow spots in the app.

Comment: please see my update for more info

Answer (score 0):

You can verify it by checking sql*net% wait event on the AWR Report.